# Preventing memory disclosure leaks for piped commands

Tags: shell-script, pipe, encryption

I'm setting up a batch job re-encrypting (transcoding? transcrypting?) files, and I'm concerned about the possibility of memory disclosure leaking plaintext.  This flaw may have other names, but basically the concern is that plaintext from an intermediate stages of the re-encrypting process could end up written to disk by another process.  This can happen when the memory that had the plaintext is freed, but not cleared, and some other process grabs the memory and that memory gets written to disk (either by swap or writing blocks larger than needed, etc.)  As an embedded programmer, I am used to clearing sensitive memory before freeing it.  However, when doing encryption from the command line I'm not sure what happens.
Say my batch process is something like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in input.enc -K $(get key command) -iv $(get iv command) \
| gpg –encrypt -r user@email -o output.gpg
```

Here there are several sources of sensitive information.  The key command, the IV command are two, but the most sensitive is the pipe between `openssl` and `gpg` which will have the plaintext data from the decrypt.

Can I be sure the memory used to hold the plaintext output from `openssl` as it is piped to `gpg` will be cleared by the operating system before given to another process?  If not, is there something I can do to force that to happen?  I don't ever want another process to obtain a memory block that could have the plaintext data.  I typically use `bash` if there is a bash-specific solution.

Comment: Memory given to a process will be zeroed. However the key and iv will be visible to commands like `ps`. Users with sufficient privilege (which probably just means root) will me able to read the memory of the processes. Programs able to monitor system calls can also see the buffers associated with system calls. Data can also be written to swap space, which also can be dumped and examined. So there will be no accidental leakage, but a determined attacker who can elevate their access will be able to see the plaintext.

Comment: Thank you.  I am less worried about an attacker than I am about accidentally preserving sensitive data.  Are you able to point to a source that confirms memory given to a process will be zeroed?

Comment: Yes. There are 3 ways a process can get memory from the OS. The brk/sbrk system call to extend the allocated memory. This is the original way used for 45 years used for the heap for C programs. The mmap system call, to map in an anonymous region.  These deal with explicit requests. Thirdly a page fault which appears to  be caused by the stack growing. All three routes return zero'ed memory. Since you are exposing the key and iv to everyone via `ps`, but are more worried about an accident than an attacker I wonder what your threat model actually is.

Comment: I am not trying to protect against the root user.  The only threat is plaintext remnants that could, in any way, be written to permanent storage after the re-encryption takes place.  That includes in key and iv.  In the past, memory disclosure leaking caused by not clearing memory could cause this to happen--maybe not in Linux, but in other operating systems.  Always returning cleared memory would ensure this as long as all program, including (and especially) kernel drivers, get their memory this way.  Perhaps this is just my age showing and the issue has been moot for a long time.

Comment: One process inheriting memory from another process has never been a problem on Linux. However, depending on what else is running, if the key and IV are part of the command arguments, they could end up being logged to disk.

Comment: @StephenKitt Could you elaborate?  What could cause the key and IV to be logged to disk?

Comment: Auditing — some systems are set up to log all commands run on them, *e.g.* using `auditd` (the basic `acct` logs commands, but not their arguments). Presumably if you’re running this on a system you administer, you’ll know whether that’s the case or not ;-).